# Find possible language construct that is written inside a string

Tags: php

I have a string:

`$string = 't["t1="] = test["that"]."point!";';`

And am trying to find the `=` that is responsible for the language construct. This is so far what I have:

```
$length = strlen($string);
$values = array();
$was = false;
$now = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    switch($sting[$i]) { 
        case '"':
            if(empty($now) || $now != "string") {
                $now = "string";
            } else if($now == "string") {
                $now = false;
            }
        break;
        case '=':
            if($now != "string") {
                echo "found the language construct";
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

I am wondering if I can shorten this down so I can later find other language constructs such as `.` and `;`.

Thanks.

Comment: you could use a php parser to analyze your strings https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that I'm trying to create a parser myself. I need it done in a specific manner as well... :/